# How to dublicate comments on my site to facebook?

Tags: facebook

I use fb comments plugin on my website. How can I dublicate comments below my articles on my website to fb and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t.

Facebook has experimented with a feature called “comment mirroring” for a while, that achieved exactly that. But they have since removed it again.

You could of course read your comments from your Facebook posts, and display them *in addition* to the comments plugin. But you won’t be able to mix them both together.

And there is no real way for you to push comments the other direction, from your page, to your Facebook posts. The only thing you might be able to do, is publish them *as* your page, not under the original user name. But I would be careful with that, that could have legal implications, if something someone else wrote, all of the sudden gets presented as if it was written by your page.